# Golang GORM - How to use REGEXP in where condition?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I need an insight about Query in Golang using Gorm, especially for REGEXP condition. 
Here is my code, in where condition :

```
query.Where("`user`.`project_ids` REGEXP @project_ids", map[string]interface{}{
      "project_ids": `\\b` + strconv.Itoa(chat_project) + `\\b`,
})
```

And the query Raw is :

```
SELECT
    `user`.id,
    `user`.email,
    `user`.client_id,
    `user`.masking_number_id,
    `user`.last_login_attempt,
    `user`.project_ids,
    `user`.role,
    `user`.username,
    `user`.session_id,
    `user`.status,
    user_agent_role.assign,
    user_agent_role.created_by,
    user_agent_role.created_date,
    user_agent_role.invite,
    user_agent_role.pinned,
    user_agent_role.transfer,
    user_agent_role.user_id
FROM
    `user`
INNER JOIN user_agent_role ON `user`.id = user_agent_role.user_id
WHERE
    `user`.`role` = 'agent' AND `user`.`status` = 10 AND `user`.`project_ids` REGEXP '\\b476\\b'
```

After checking at SQLyog that query working fine and shows 17 rows. But gorm result shows 0.

[image]

What happened with gorm ? and the weirdest is when i try to hardcode that query to this :

```
query.Where("`user`.`project_ids` REGEXP '\\\\b476\\\\b'")
```

it is working fine and shows 17 rows, same with direct query in SQLyog.

Comment: Did you try to surround `@project_ids` with single quotes (') in the code that doesn't work?